# Where can I find a gallery of all the standard winforms widgets?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

I just want a URL to a gallery of widgets such as [this one](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/), but for the default WinForms controls that come standard with Visual Studio 2012.

I ran VS and I open the "Toolbox" view and it shows about 150 different widgets. I just want to see a simple picture of each one on a single web pages so I know roughly what they look like.

I tried Google and [found this,](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Controls.html) which is WPF and shows very few pictures.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a WinForm open the Toolbox has an All Controls option - you can open that and take a couple of screenshots.